# Moment.js not displaying results

Tags: javascript, html, momentjs

I'm having problem displaying 24hr time string converted to 12hr format using moment.js still looking for a solution

html code

```
<div id="showtime"></div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
(function()
{
  // instantiate a moment object
  var convert24hr = moment("15:30", "HH:mm").format("hh:mm A");

  // display value of moment object in #displayMoment div
  var eDisplayMoment = document.getElementById('showtime');
  eDisplayMoment.innerHTML = convert24hr;

})();
</script>
```

**Update**
Forgot to add CSS to styles

```
#showtime {
    font-size:30px;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4uvk6fm1/1/ - looks just fine

Comment: is there any error in your browser console - whether the script is placed after the element in your markup

Comment: Oh darn I had to make a CSS selector its all fixed. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I forgot to add CSS to stylesheet updated code below

```
#showtime {
    font-size:30px;
}
```